MOSFET Heatsink?
I'm new to electronics, and have just discovered that MOSFET's need heatsinks to stop them blowing out (you'd think they would have mentioned this at uni?).
I'm using a RFD16N016LE (datasheet: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/RFD16N06LESM-99391.pdf), with a max continuous current of 5A and 12V max voltage; how do I know what heatsink I need to use? And how do I connect it? Does anyone have any guides I can read to learn this stuff?


The heatsink depends on your APPLICATION, not the specific device. Start by specifiying how much power the application will require the device to dissipate.

with a max continuous current of 5A and 12V max voltage can you give more details about the application? Is it going to be switching the load or part of a linear regulator or something else? A schematic is also needed, even a hand-drawn one would be good to have.

Yes sorry, switching between 2A and 4.5A, with heating element (0.3 ohm resistor in schematic), the two voltage sources are arduino output pins so either on (5V) or off :) @RohatKılıç

Please explain your design, in particular why you have two MOSFETs in parallel but driven differently. You say "switching" but the design appears to perform current regulation. What are BCK and BST?

I want a background current of 2A which turns on based on an arduino pin (BCK), and a boost current of 4.5A, turned on by a different arduino pin (BST), the pins are respresented by the two voltage sources on the left. The rest is simply what I came up with to achieve that goal, using my limited knowledge given to my by my first year at uni, please let me know if what I've done is stupid :) @Finbarr

The same current flows through the 0.3 Ohm heater element and the 1 Ohm resistor, so it should be fairly obvious that the resistor is going to produce just over three times as much heat as the heating element. Why have you not considered using PWM instead?

I've not considered it because I've never heard of it lol, could you please explain? @Finbarr

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation - it's the method used by things like dimmer switches to control brightness without generating huge amounts of heat.

Whether you need a heatsink or not, and how big of one you need, depends on what you're doing--it's not true that MOSFETs need heatsinks in general, but power MOSFETs frequently are used in applications where they do.

You sort of start to work your way backwards.
You have an ambient temperature, lets say 25 degrees. Then you specify what you can tolerate as the maximum junction temperature. The datasheet will give you the maximum, usually 150-175 degrees.
With a dissipated power of 12V*5A = 60W you will get a required thermal resistance of maximum: (175C-25C)/60W = 2.5C/W.
As you can see this is far from the 80C/W (junction-to-ambient) given in the datasheet which is given WITHOUT any heatsink other than the bare minimum of the recommended PCB footprint.
So to achieve this you have to put the MOSFET on a PCB here you can use the 1.65C/W and then you can only add so much extra thermal resistance to reach the 2.5C/W. (2.5C/W - 1.65C/W) = 0.85C/W as your heatsink.
As you can see this is hard to achieve and I also used the highest junction temperature, maybe you only would like to use 125C, which makes it even harder, so here it could be that you use more FETs in parallel or a bigger one with a lower theta_JC.

To add to this, for a complexer application would you say that the shape of the Heatsink can also be helpful since its heat dissipation capacity is correlated to the surface area provided?

@Tyassin thank you very much! Multiple FETs in parallel is an idea I'd not considered, suppose I put another FET in parallel, halving the power through each and thereby (roughly) doubling the max thermal resistance for the heatsink, could I connect a single heatsink of that smaller size to both of them? Or would I need one each? Thanks

As you mention the power dissipated in each FET is in theory halved. But the power to the heatsink is still the same.

Firstly, your circuit is trying to control the MOSFETs linearly yet, the data sheet tells you that they might be an unwise choice for that type of application: -
They were designed for use in applications such as switching regulators, switching 
converters, motor drivers, relay drivers and emitter switches for bipolar transistors.

And, the reason they are not suitable for linear applications is because of thermal runaway: -

I've added a blue circle where thermal runaway can occur. Now, if you look in the data sheets for any MOSFETs there is always an area where an increase in temperature will produce a significant increase in drain current (potential for thermal runaway). This will happen when the gate-source voltage is held constant so you can't really prevent this from happening.
However, MOSFETs designed for linear applications will cope with this and not fry.
When I say "fry" I actually mean be subject to a massive surge in drain current that happens in less than 10 ms. That surge will occur in a localized hot-spot within the MOSFET and destroy it. This will happen irrespective of whether you have a heatsink or not. In other words, having a heat sink won't prevent this from happening.
This is a more detailed tear-down of the problem with links to other places: -
What they didn't tell me about MOSFETs when I was at college

Hi Andy -- FYI, negative tempco does not unconditionally lead to thermal runaway.  It is a necessary, but not sufficient condition. Critically, thermal conductivity of the die and mounting base also play a role -- which is never documented, therefore we cannot infer stability curves from datasheet information alone. I will leave this note on the linked answers as well so that readers are aware. Cheers.

Thanks for your answer :) Could you recommend a good linear MOSFET for this? I'm struggling to find one via google searches @Andy aka

@Dip Littelfuse/IXYS linear application MOSFETs

This is where it's good to have a multimeter with a thermistor to measure the temperature in real time usage. Or a thermal camera or any type of probe. Whenever I needed a heat sink in the past I would do a brute force approach, where I just add pieces of metal I have lying around (if I didn't have the appropriate heat sink) and see how well it dissipates the heat. If it's in an enclosure I would consider adding a small PC fan on it with vents everywhere. I find it's not an exact science and even a small heat sink goes a long way to keeping it cool
